# ECLIPSE Photon (4.8) SWT MENU ON WINDOWS 10 did not work

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, windows-10, swt

the following Code runs under Ubuntu and Eclpise Oxygen.The Menu ist displayed. In Windows 10 and Eclipse Photon the Menu is not there. Is there any solution.

```
menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR)
menuDefaultHeader = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE)
menuDefaultHeader.setText("Default");

menuDefault = new Menu(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
menuDefaultHeader.setMenu(menuDefault);

menuDefaultClock = new MenuItem(menuDefault, SWT.PUSH);
menuDefaultClock.setText("&Clock");
```

Comment: You should show us a proper [mcve] so that people can test this easily. Also note the Eclipse Photon is still only in pre-release Milestone builds and won't be finally released until June. If you must use Photon make sure you are on the newest milestone (currently 4.8M6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either start with the `Shell`'s existing menu bar from `#getMenuBar()` as the root of your menus, or explicitly set your created `Menu` with its `BAR` style as the new menu bar with `#setMenuBar()`. That it's worked so far is a combination of implementation details and blind luck.

See the [example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet29.java#n28).